# MPI Segmentation Fault while running with 4 processes

Tags: c, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, mpi

I wrote my parallel version of unix grep program. In this program you search for patter in files given as program arguments.

In root process I calculate number of files per process and first file ID for each process. After calculations I send this values to each of root processes.

In not root process I'm receiving num of Files and first file ID and analyzing each file in analyzeFile method. In that method I send back string, which contains all lines with pattern, to root process. After collecting all data from not root precesses I print out final result.

The problem is when I try to run program with more than 3 processes. It ends up with segmentation fault.

I'm out of ideas. Valgrind does not show any error reports on base scanning.

PS. I know that code needs refactoring, but first I want to get rid of this bug.

Thanks for any help.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <mpi.h>

#define YEL   "\x1B[33m"
#define BLU   "\x1B[34m"
#define MAG   "\x1B[35m"
#define RESET "\x1B[0m"

#define send_data_tag 1000
#define return_data_tag 1001

struct      linesRange
{
    int lineFrom;
    int lineTo;
    int posFrom;
    int posTo;
};


int countNumOfLines(char *str)
{
    int         numOfLines = 0;
    int         i = 0;

    while(str[i] != '\0')
    {
        if(str[i] == '\n')
        {
            ++numOfLines;
        }

        ++i;
    }

    return numOfLines;
}

long int findLinePos(char *str, int lineNumToFind)
{
    long int    linePos = 0;
    long int        lineNum = 0;
    long int        i = 0;

    if(lineNumToFind == 0)
    {
        return linePos;
    }

    while(str[i] != '\0')
    {
        if(str[i] == '\n')
        {
        ++lineNum;

        if(lineNum == lineNumToFind)
        {
            linePos = i;
            break;
        }
    }

    ++i;
}

return linePos;
}


long int findNextLinePos(char *str, int startPos)
{
    long int i              = startPos;
    long int nextLinePos        = 0;

    while(str[i] != '\0')
    {
        if(str[i] == '\n')
        {
            nextLinePos = i;
            break;
        }

        ++i;
    }

    return nextLinePos;
}

bool strstrn(char *str, char *pattern, long int posStart, long int posEnd)
{
long int pos_search = 0;
long int pos_text = 0;
int len_search = strlen(pattern);

for (pos_text = posStart; pos_text < posEnd; ++pos_text)
{
    if(str[pos_text] == pattern[pos_search])
    {
        ++pos_search;
        if(pos_search == len_search)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    else
    {
       pos_text -= pos_search;
       pos_search = 0;
    }
}

return false;
}

char * searchPatternInText(char *text, char *inputPattern, char *fileName, int proc_id)
{
char *bufToAdd;
int  lineNum = 0;

char * resultBuf = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char));

memset(resultBuf, 0, sizeof(char));

char * curLine = text;

while(curLine)
{
    ++lineNum;  

    char * nextLine = strchr(curLine, '\n');

    if (nextLine) 
        *nextLine = '\0';

    if(strstr(curLine, inputPattern))
    {
        bufToAdd    = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char));

        memset(bufToAdd, 0, sizeof(char));

        asprintf (&bufToAdd, BLU "Ścieżka:%s\tProces:%d\n" MAG "Numer linii:%d\t" RESET "%s\n", fileName, proc_id, lineNum, curLine);

        resultBuf = (char*)realloc(resultBuf, strlen(resultBuf) + strlen(bufToAdd) + 1);

        strcat(resultBuf, bufToAdd);

        free(bufToAdd);
    }

    if (nextLine) 
        *nextLine = '\n';

    curLine = nextLine ? (nextLine+ 1) : NULL;
}

return resultBuf;
}


void analyzeFile(struct stat sb, int fd, char *fileName, char *pattern, int proc_id)
{
char        *text       = mmap (0, sb.st_size, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);

if (text == MAP_FAILED) {
    perror ("mmap");
    return;
}

if (close (fd) == -1)
{
    perror ("close");
    return;
}


char *tempTxt;

tempTxt     = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen(text) + 1));

strcpy(tempTxt, text);

tempTxt[strlen(text)] = '\0';

//munmap(text, sb.st_size);

char *result;

result = searchPatternInText(tempTxt, pattern, fileName, proc_id);

free(tempTxt);


if(proc_id != 0)
{                       
    MPI_Send(result, strlen(result), MPI_CHAR,
                0, return_data_tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
}   
else
{
    printf(result);
}

free(result);       
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
int         patternLen = 10;
char        pattern [patternLen + 1];
float       elapsed;
int         numOfFiles = argc - 2;
int         proc_id, num_procs, procIterator, filesIterator, root = 0;
int         *numOfFilesPerProcess, *firstFileIdPerProcess;


if (argc < 3) {
    fprintf (stderr, "usage: %s <file>\n", argv[0]);
            return 1;
    }
else
{
    strncpy(pattern, argv[1], patternLen);
    pattern[patternLen] = '\0';
}



MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);

MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &proc_id);
MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &num_procs);

MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
double  startTime = MPI_Wtime();

if(proc_id == root)
{
    MPI_Status  statusMaster;       

    numOfFilesPerProcess    = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * num_procs);
    firstFileIdPerProcess   = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * num_procs);

    for(int i = 0; i < num_procs; ++i)
    {
        numOfFilesPerProcess[i]     = 0;

        firstFileIdPerProcess[i]    = 0;
    }

    filesIterator   = 0;
    procIterator    = 0;

    while(filesIterator < numOfFiles)
    {
        if(procIterator == num_procs)
        {
            procIterator = 0;
        }

        ++numOfFilesPerProcess[procIterator];

        ++procIterator;
        ++filesIterator;
    }

    firstFileIdPerProcess[0] = 2;

    //pierwszy numer argumentu argv[] per proces

    for(int jj = 1; jj < num_procs; ++jj)
    {
        firstFileIdPerProcess[jj] = firstFileIdPerProcess[jj - 1] + numOfFilesPerProcess[jj - 1];
    }

    for(int j = 1; j < num_procs; ++j)
    {
        MPI_Send(&firstFileIdPerProcess[j], 1, MPI_UNSIGNED,
                    j, send_data_tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD);          

        MPI_Send(&numOfFilesPerProcess[j], 1, MPI_UNSIGNED,
                    j, send_data_tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    }


    int         firstFileIdForProcess   =   firstFileIdPerProcess[0];
    int         numOfFilesForProcess    =   numOfFilesPerProcess[0];
    int         fd;
    struct      stat sb;

    for(int i = 0; i < numOfFilesForProcess; ++i)
    {
        fd = open (argv[firstFileIdForProcess + i], O_RDONLY);

        if (    fd == -1
            || fstat (fd, &sb) == -1
            || !S_ISREG (sb.st_mode))
        {
            perror("file");
        }
        else
        {
            analyzeFile(sb, fd, argv[firstFileIdForProcess + i], pattern, proc_id);
        }
    }


    for(int ii = numOfFilesPerProcess[0]; ii < numOfFiles; ++ii)
    {
        int         resultLen;  
        char        *result;    

        MPI_Probe(MPI_ANY_SOURCE, return_data_tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &statusMaster);

        MPI_Get_count(&statusMaster, MPI_CHAR, &resultLen);

        result = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * resultLen + 1);

        MPI_Recv( result, resultLen, MPI_CHAR,
                  MPI_ANY_SOURCE, return_data_tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &statusMaster);

        result[resultLen] = '\0';

        printf(result);

        free(result);
    }

    free(numOfFilesPerProcess);
    free(firstFileIdPerProcess);

}
else
{
    MPI_Status  statusSlave;        

    int         firstFileIdForProcess = 0;
    int         numOfFilesForProcess = 0;
    int         fd;
    struct      stat sb;

    MPI_Recv( &firstFileIdForProcess, 1, MPI_UNSIGNED,
              root, send_data_tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &statusSlave);

    MPI_Recv( &numOfFilesForProcess, 1, MPI_UNSIGNED,
              root, send_data_tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &statusSlave);


    for(int i = 0; i < numOfFilesForProcess; ++i)
    {
        fd = open (argv[firstFileIdForProcess + i], O_RDONLY);

        if (    fd == -1
            || fstat (fd, &sb) == -1
            || !S_ISREG (sb.st_mode))
        {
            perror("file");
        }
        else
        {
            analyzeFile(sb, fd, argv[firstFileIdForProcess + i], pattern, proc_id);
        }
    }       

  }

MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
double  endTime = MPI_Wtime();

if(proc_id == root)
{   
    printf("Czas wykonania: %fs\n", endTime - startTime);
}

MPI_Finalize();

return 0;
}
```

Comment: your code isn't verifiable. where did you define `send_data_tag`? please provide minimal, working, and verifiable code (including required headers).

Comment: what value do you get in `resultLen` ?

Comment: I added whole code

Comment: Unless its huge, add the file to open as well.

Comment: https://spaces.hightail.com/space/StR2XDVP4i here is my file in .c

Comment: I am not talking about the `.c` file but the file needed to provide as command line argument (`mpirun -n 3 ./a.out file_to_open`)

Comment: Oh, sorry. I added txtFilesGrep.tar.gz file to space at  
spaces.hightail.com/space/StR2XDVP4i, which contains 4 txt files. Program crushes, when I try to search pattern 'a' in all 4 files with 4 processes.
Thansk, for help ! :)

Comment: Works fine for me.